# Downloading attachments from rally using C# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, api, rally

My ultimate goal in the script I am writing is to download all attachments from rally.  I was able to successfully connect to the server, make a request for all attachments in a workspace, and finally, iterate through to retrieve the content of each attachment.  This yields a dynamicJsonObject of the "AttachmentContent".  Being new to any API as well C# and .NET, I am now stuck.  I cannot figure out a way to access and download the content of this object to a file on my computer.  The line I have commented below is where I am currently getting an error and am stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

P.S. Here is my main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@company.com", "password", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.43");
        Request request = new Request("attachment");
        request.Workspace = "/workspace/186282018";
        request.Fetch = new List<string>() { "Name", "Artifact", "Content", "ContentType" };
        request.Query = new Query("");
        QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
        {     
            DynamicJsonObject content = result["Content"];
            //var binContent = content["Content"];
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that simply writes the content bytes to a File and skips the mime-type checking:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace RestExample_DownloadAttachment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;

            // Rally parameters
            String userName = "user@company.com";
            String userPassword = "topsecret";
            String rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String wsapiVersion = "1.43";

            restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                userName,
                userPassword,
                rallyURL,
                wsapiVersion
            );


            //Set our Workspace and Project scopings
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345678910";
            String projectRef = "/project/12345678911";
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = true;

            // Find User Story that we want to pull attachment from

            // Tee up Story Request
            Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
            storyRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            storyRequest.Project = projectRef;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;

            // Fields to Fetch
            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "Attachments"
                };

            // Add a query
            storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "US163");

            // Query Rally for the Story
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(storyRequest);

            // Pull reference off of Story fetch
            DynamicJsonObject storyObject = queryResult.Results.First();
            String storyReference = storyObject["_ref"];
            Console.WriteLine("Looking for attachments off of Story: " + storyReference);

            // Grab the Attachments collection
            var storyAttachments = storyObject["Attachments"];
            // Let's download the first attachment for starters
            var myAttachmentFromStory = storyAttachments[0];
            // Pull the ref
            String myAttachmentRef = myAttachmentFromStory["_ref"];
            Console.WriteLine("Found Attachment: " + myAttachmentRef);

            // Fetch fields for the Attachment
            string[] attachmentFetch = { "ObjectID", "Name", "Content", "ContentType", "Size"};

            // Now query for the attachment
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentObject = restApi.GetByReference(myAttachmentRef, "true");

            // Grab the AttachmentContent
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentContentFromAttachment = attachmentObject["Content"];
            String attachmentContentRef = attachmentContentFromAttachment["_ref"];

            // Lastly pull the content
            // Fetch fields for the Attachment
            string[] attachmentContentFetch = { "ObjectID", "Content" };

            // Now query for the attachment
            Console.WriteLine("Querying for Content...");
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentContentObject = restApi.GetByReference(attachmentContentRef, "true");
            Console.WriteLine("AttachmentContent: " + attachmentObject["_ref"]);

            String base64EncodedContent = attachmentContentObject["Content"];

            // File information
            String attachmentSavePath = "C:\\Users\\username\\";
            String attachmentFileName = attachmentObject["Name"];
            String fullAttachmentFile = attachmentSavePath + attachmentFileName; 

            // Determine attachment Content mime-type
            String attachmentContentType = attachmentObject["ContentType"];

            try {

                // Output base64 content to File
                Console.WriteLine("Saving base64 AttachmentContent String to File.");

                File.WriteAllBytes(@fullAttachmentFile, Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedContent));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception occurred while writing file: " + e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A perfect answer.  Thank you very much, Mark W!

Answer (score 2):

Following is a brief example illustrating the procedure to download attachment content. It's limited in its type handling to a few common image types, but it illustrates the idea:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace RestExample_DownloadAttachment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;

            // Rally parameters
            String userName = "user@company.com";
            String userPassword = "topsecret";
            String rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String wsapiVersion = "1.43";

            restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                userName,
                userPassword,
                rallyURL,
                wsapiVersion
            );

            //Set our Workspace and Project scopings
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345678910";
            String projectRef = "/project/12345678911";
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = true;

            // Find User Story that we want to pull attachment from

            // Tee up Story Request
            Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
            storyRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            storyRequest.Project = projectRef;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;

            // Fields to Fetch
            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "Attachments"
                };

            // Add a query
            storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "US43");

            // Query Rally for the Story
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(storyRequest);

            // Pull reference off of Story fetch
            DynamicJsonObject storyObject = queryResult.Results.First();
            String storyReference = storyObject["_ref"];
            Console.WriteLine("Looking for attachments off of Story: " + storyReference);

            // Grab the Attachments collection
            var storyAttachments = storyObject["Attachments"];
            // Let's download the first attachment for starters
            var myAttachmentFromStory = storyAttachments[0];
            // Pull the ref
            String myAttachmentRef = myAttachmentFromStory["_ref"];
            Console.WriteLine("Found Attachment: " + myAttachmentRef);

            // Fetch fields for the Attachment
            string[] attachmentFetch = { "ObjectID", "Name", "Content", "ContentType", "Size"};

            // Now query for the attachment
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentObject = restApi.GetByReference(myAttachmentRef, "true");

            // Grab the AttachmentContent
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentContentFromAttachment = attachmentObject["Content"];
            String attachmentContentRef = attachmentContentFromAttachment["_ref"];

            // Lastly pull the content
            // Fetch fields for the Attachment
            string[] attachmentContentFetch = { "ObjectID", "Content" };

            // Now query for the attachment
            Console.WriteLine("Querying for Content...");
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentContentObject = restApi.GetByReference(attachmentContentRef, "true");
            Console.WriteLine("AttachmentContent: " + attachmentObject["_ref"]);

            String base64EncodedContent = attachmentContentObject["Content"];

            // File information
            String attachmentSavePath = "C:\\Users\\username\\";
            String attachmentFileName = attachmentObject["Name"];
            String fullAttachmentFile = attachmentSavePath + attachmentFileName; 

            // Determine attachment Content mime-type
            String attachmentContentType = attachmentObject["ContentType"];

            // Specify Image format
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat attachmentImageFormat;

            try
            {
                attachmentImageFormat = getImageFormat(attachmentContentType);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid attachment file format:" + e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("Don't know how to handle: " + attachmentContentType);
                return;
            }

            try {

                // Convert base64 content to Image
                Console.WriteLine("Converting base64 AttachmentContent String to Image.");

                // Convert Base64 string to bytes
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedContent);

                Image myAttachmentImage;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    myAttachmentImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    // Save the image
                    Console.WriteLine("Saving Image: " + fullAttachmentFile);
                    myAttachmentImage.Save(fullAttachmentFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    Console.WriteLine("Finished Saving Attachment: " + fullAttachmentFile);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception occurred: " + e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Returns an ImageFormat type based on Rally contentType / mime-type
        public static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat getImageFormat(String contentType)
        {
            // Save Image format
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat attachmentImageFormat;

            switch (contentType)
            {
                case "image/png":
                    attachmentImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;
                case "image/jpeg":
                    attachmentImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
                case "image/tiff":
                    attachmentImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid image file format.");
                    throw new System.ArgumentException("Invalid attachment file format.");
            };

            return attachmentImageFormat;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  But I still don't understand why I get an error at that one line of code.  It seems as if you write the same line: String base64EncodedContent = attachmentContentObject["Content"];
Yet, when I attempt to retrieve the content from my attachment object, I get a "Key not found" error.

Comment: Now that I realize it, my example is coded against an earlier version of the REST .NET DLL. Let me re-factor to use the current and test, just to make sure we're comparing the same things.

Comment: Ok - I verified that my code works against the current (1.0.15) version of the REST .NET DLL. As for why your code isn't working...If you inspect the `content` DynamicJsonObject that you have retrieved, you'll find it's just a Ref. I.E. it contains only a `_ref` field of the form: `/attachmentcontent/12345678912`, pointing to the actual AttachmentContent Object in Rally. You need to do a 2nd get, a getByReference, in order to pull the full AttachmentContent object and its fields.

Comment: Please review my example carefully. You'll note that after retrieving the Attachment Object itself, I then do a 2nd getByReference: `DynamicJsonObject attachmentContentObject = restApi.GetByReference(attachmentContentRef, "true");` To pull the AttachmentContent Object, which contains the Content Base64 string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses.  They have helped me understand so much! The only problem is most of my attachments are word or excel files and some are even .rar.  Do you have any tips on how to write these to files?  Or could you possibly point me in the right direction of some documentation on this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The image example was probably a bit too specific with the mime-type checking and Image file formats. I've posted a second answer that just writes the AttachmentContent to a file letting the file extension map the type, and calls it good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same example from  user984832 but modified to work with v2.0 of WS API, and 2.0.1 dll of the [Rally REST toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace DownloadAttachment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RallyRestApi restApi;

            String userName = "user@co.com";
            String userPassword = "secret";

            String rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";

            restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                userName,
                userPassword,
                rallyURL,
                wsapiVersion
            );

            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129";
            String projectRef = "/project/12352608219";
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = true;

            Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
            storyRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            storyRequest.Project = projectRef;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;

            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "Attachments"
                };

            storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "US20");
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(storyRequest);
            DynamicJsonObject story = queryResult.Results.First();

            // Grab the Attachments collection
            Request attachmentsRequest = new Request(story["Attachments"]);
            QueryResult attachmentsResult = restApi.Query(attachmentsRequest);

            //Download the first attachment

            var myAttachmentFromStory = attachmentsResult.Results.First();
            String myAttachmentRef = myAttachmentFromStory["_ref"];
            Console.WriteLine("Found Attachment: " + myAttachmentRef);

            // Fetch fields for the Attachment
            string[] attachmentFetch = { "ObjectID", "Name", "Content", "ContentType", "Size" };

            // Now query for the attachment
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentObject = restApi.GetByReference(myAttachmentRef, "true");

            // Grab the AttachmentContent
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentContentFromAttachment = attachmentObject["Content"];
            String attachmentContentRef = attachmentContentFromAttachment["_ref"];

            // Lastly pull the content
            // Fetch fields for the Attachment
            string[] attachmentContentFetch = { "ObjectID", "Content" };

            // Now query for the attachment
            Console.WriteLine("Querying for Content...");
            DynamicJsonObject attachmentContentObject = restApi.GetByReference(attachmentContentRef, "true");
            Console.WriteLine("AttachmentContent: " + attachmentObject["_ref"]);

            String base64EncodedContent = attachmentContentObject["Content"];

            // File information
            String attachmentSavePath = "C:\\Users\\nmusaelian\\NewFolder";
            String attachmentFileName = attachmentObject["Name"];
            String fullAttachmentFile = attachmentSavePath + attachmentFileName;

            // Determine attachment Content mime-type
            String attachmentContentType = attachmentObject["ContentType"];

            // Specify Image format
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat attachmentImageFormat;

            try
            {
                attachmentImageFormat = getImageFormat(attachmentContentType);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid attachment file format:" + e.StackTrace);
            }

            try
            {

                // Convert base64 content to Image
                Console.WriteLine("Converting base64 AttachmentContent String to Image.");

                // Convert Base64 string to bytes
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedContent);

                Image myAttachmentImage;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    myAttachmentImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    // Save the image
                    Console.WriteLine("Saving Image: " + fullAttachmentFile);
                    myAttachmentImage.Save(fullAttachmentFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    Console.WriteLine("Finished Saving Attachment: " + fullAttachmentFile);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception occurred: " + e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Returns an ImageFormat type based on Rally contentType / mime-type
        public static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat getImageFormat(String contentType)
        {
            // Save Image format
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat attachmentImageFormat;

            switch (contentType)
            {
                case "image/png":
                    attachmentImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;
                case "image/jpeg":
                    attachmentImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
                case "image/tiff":
                    attachmentImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid image file format.");
                    throw new System.ArgumentException("Invalid attachment file format.");
            };

            return attachmentImageFormat;
        }
    }
}
```